# domain admin account unable to modify IE settings, other DOMadmin group accounts can

Tags: security, group-policy, windows, internet-explorer

When I log into one of the servers on our domain as DOMAIN\administrator, IE settings are locked, and indicate that I'll have to check with the system administrator.

If I log into the same server with my domain account, which is in the domain administrators group, I can modify these settings without any difficulty.

I'm assuming that this is caused by a GPO, but I have searched pretty thoroughly through GPManagement, and run GP Results, and cannot identify any GPO that is causing this behavior.

Has anyone seen this?  Further troubleshooting tips are welcome!  Need to find this to fix a security level issue that's preventing a critical app from functioning.

(primarily on Windows Server 2012, but also seems to be the case on previous versions of Windows Server)

Comment: `rsop.msc` and `gpresult /z`

Comment: `1.` Why not fix it using the account that does work? `2.` If you're running the application with the domain Administrator credentials and that's why you need to fix this then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Check the local users and groups. Is the Administrator Account a member of the Administrators Group? It may have been removed locally and/or in AD.